# Is the "new" theme being shown on questions going to "take"?

Tags: discussion

There is a new "theme" that is being tested on questions this morning (Sunday March 31, 2019).  Is this theme going to become permanent?  (I hope not, because it's really ugly!)

Comment: I like it. It pops.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not.

This is simply a an April Fools joke. It'll be gone by Tuesday.

You can learn more by perusing the [April Fools tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/April-Fools) on Meta.SE.